# How to get App_Data folder with .mdf file in ASP.NET MVC app? (tried to show all files)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, database, app-data

I want to create a database connection, but can't find the solution.

Tried to show all files and a lot of different methods on this site.
VS doesn't create `App_Data` folder and I want to know how to work with it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Free advice: **Don't do this!** If you want to use SQL Server - use a proper, fully installed version of SQL Server - don't fiddle around with free-floating `.mdf` files in various directories - that'll just cause a lot of grief and headaches in the long run! Put your database **on the server** where it belongs - and just reference that server.